# Dockers on DC/OS 1.8: First one works, the rest are dead

Tags: containers, mesos, marathon, dcos

I have a container that will be deployed several times upon request from my application, the difference between containers relies on the environment variables, they point to a different bd (PostgreSQL) and a different table (the table represents the path property of the health check). When I deploy the first service on my DC/OS 1.8 it works like a charm, however, the rest of the deployments don't work.

My `app.json` looks as follows:

```
{
  "volumes": null,
  "id": "/data-microservices/ms1",
  "cmd": null,
  "args": null,
  "user": null,
  "env": {
    "DATABASE_URL": "postgres://<username>:<password>@<host>:5432/<dbname>",
    "TABLE": "<thetable>"
  },
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 65,
  "disk": 0,
  "gpus": 0,
  "backoffSeconds": 1,
  "backoffFactor": 1.15,
  "maxLaunchDelaySeconds": 3600,
  "container": {
    "docker": {
      "image": "imtachu/data-microservice",
      "forcePullImage": true,
      "privileged": false,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "network": "BRIDGE"
    }
  },
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "path": "/api/<thetable>",
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 10,
      "intervalSeconds": 2,
      "timeoutSeconds": 10,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 10,
      "ignoreHttp1xx": false
    }
  ],
  "readinessChecks": null,
  "dependencies": null,
  "upgradeStrategy": {
    "minimumHealthCapacity": 1,
    "maximumOverCapacity": 1
  },
  "labels": {
    "HAPROXY_GROUP": "external",
    "HAPROXY_0_VHOST": "dcos2-PublicSlaveL-KWSCFODW1ME5-878889582.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "acceptedResourceRoles": null,
  "residency": null,
  "secrets": null,
  "taskKillGracePeriodSeconds": null,
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ],
  "requirePorts": false
}
```

So far, I have tried to modify the `hostPort` property and changing the `HAPROXY_0_VHOST` to `HAPROXY_1_VHOST` also the `requirePorts` so maybe I can have each container running on a different port.

I have tried deploying first a service pointing to table A and then another pointing to table B and viceversa, and the behavior is the same: First deployed service always work, the rest doesn't.

Comment: Without logs it's really hard to tell, there could be many reasons. Can you join us on the DC/OS Community Slack (chat.dcos.io) and we take it from there?

Comment: Do you deploy this multiple times, or do you scale vi the instance count? And what exactly doesn't work, meaning are there any error messages?

Comment: @Tobi Thats the awful thing, there's not an error, the service is "Running" and the health check seems successful. Yes, I deploy the service multiple times, they generate different (non-repetitive) endpoints

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas Yes! I am already at slack, will keep it from there, thanks!